# what will be the config section when adding a section to web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, ldap

I want to add domain key and value to my web.config for ldap authentication but when adding

```
<domain>
   <add key="don"  value="fffT"/>
   <add key="LD" value="LDAP://n.tt.sg/DC=ttt,DC=xx,DC=exxxx,DC=sg"/>
</domain>
```

it shows the error `could not find schema information of value and key`. What should i write instead of

```
  <section name="domain" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler,System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
<configuration> 
<appSettings> 
<add key="don"  value="fffT"/>
<add key="LD" value="LDAP://n.tt.sg/DC=ttt,DC=xx,DC=exxxx,DC=sg"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Put Key and values inside `appSettings` Section of web.confing

Answer (score 0):

`System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler` is from `System` assembly, not `System.Web.Extensions`.

```
type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=3.5.0.0,         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```